# Acronis Will Not Install (GPO Concerns)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

We have a group policy object that denies installation from user AppData folders. However, we are trying to install Acronis Backup software onto the environment. We are trying to deploy this application to multiple machines (100-200 machines) and it relies on our RMM to deploy it with the correct settings. This application eventually uses AppData to install onto the machines.

Is there a way to allow an application to run in AppData given the GPO settings?

Thank you for any additional information or guidance.

## GPO DETAILS

```
# Enforcement 
Policy Setting 
Apply Software Restriction Policies to the following All software files except libraries (such as DLLs) 
Apply Software Restriction Policies to the following users All users 
When applying Software Restriction Policies Ignore certificate rules 
 
# Designated File Types 
File Extension File Type 
ADE ADE File 
ADP ADP File 
BAS BAS File 
[REDACTED]

# Trusted Publishers 
Trusted publisher management Allow all administrators and users to manage user's own Trusted Publishers 
Certificate verification None 
 

Software Restriction Policies/Security Levelshide
Policy Setting 
Default Security Level Unrestricted 

# Software Restriction Policies/Additional Ruleshide
Path Ruleshide
%AppData%\*.exe 
Security Level Disallowed 
Description Don't allow executables to run from %AppData% 
Date last modified  
[REDACTED]
```

Comment: Found that this may be a problem with the registration through Acronis and not necessarily Windows Group Policy preventing install. I am now able to successfully install the software, I just cannot pair it to the tenant, but that makes this seem like a network issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the backup/installation problem turned out to be an `&` in the password.To fix this I removed the special characters from the password. After this installation was successfull with both GUI installation, and CLI installations.

Main Issue Highlights that special characters can cause problems. I myself had no luck with `&;%` in the password.

[39790: Illegal Characters on Various Operating Systems](https://kb.acronis.com/content/39790) lists that issues can arise when the following characters are used: `/ ? < > \ : * | : ."`

[15828: Acronis Backup & Recovery 10: Limitations on Special Characters in Passwords for Unattended Installation](https://kb.acronis.com/content/15828) lists that issues will arise when the following characters are used: `< > & / " ' ^`

Found the following [Acronis Documentation](https://kb.acronis.com/content/55244) on the issue.

> Troubleshooting
>
> Your password contains special characters, and you
>   receive this error while providing correct credentials:
>
> 1. Encode the password into base64 format:
>      https://www.base64encode.org/
> 2. Specify the encoded password using the
>      -base64 (for version 7.5) and -b or --base64 (for version 7.8 and 7.9) parameter. For a Windows agent, it would be:
>
>    - Acronis Backup Cloud 7.8, 7.9: register_agent.exe -o register -t cloud -a
>        https://cloud.acronis.com -u  -b -p
>    - Acronis Backup Cloud 7.5: register_msp_mms.exe register
>        https://cloud.acronis.com  -base64

Answer (score 2):

If you can get to know specific folder/file names Acronis uses inside AppData, then just make an exclusion with Security Level Unrestricted like you already have for Citrix, JRE etc in your policy.

Comment: I did not see that exclusion before. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll give it a try, make take some time to get a change control drafted.

Comment: I did allow the path through the group policy. It didn't work. I took it a step further and denied a single test pc the group policy object, and verified through GPRESULT that it didn't apply to the machine, so should not be blocking. Unfortunately, this was not successful.